# Followed sites graph api not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, graph-api, following, follow

For our project we are using the /me/followedSites graph API (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/sites-list-followed?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) for fetching the followed sites data but the api is not returning all the sites that are being followed. For the missed out sites if I unfollowed and followed them back again then they are getting picked up again by the API and it comes in result set. So I would like to know why some sites are getting ignored by the followed sites graph API and what is the root cause for these sites which are being already followed to get missed out. Has anyone faced similar issues. Any help would be great.

Note : I have also tried including $top=50 also in the query /me/followedSites?$top=50 but it is still not giving me 50 followed sites even though my total followed sites count is 56.

Answer (score 0):

Some more information - I had the same problem today and I was wondering what was different about my access or the application permissions that prevented this from working.

After trying every logical step, I went to the homepage (Sharepoint.aspx) and it showed my followed sites.  I was perplexed.  Then I unfollowed and refollowed from the homepage.   Then I could see the site in Microsoft Graph.

I wonder if the follow button at the top of pages vs. the follow star on the homepage call two different pieces of code to do the add.